# Why would a jquery selector not work in all instances where there are valid elements matching it's selector?

Tags: html, jquery-selectors

i have a simple jquery selector, to find parents and set their css, but some of the Elements which do have what the selector is looking for are missed entirely.
Those that it does find are bordered in red as per the image.

I'm looking for parent with Class ="accordion-heading".
I have tried Parents as well as parent().parents()..but it still does not see some of the elements which have this class.

the jq is

```
var fullparent = BranchChkBoxArray[i][0];
$('#' + fullparent).parent().parent(".accordion-heading").css({ "color": "red", "border": "2px solid red" });
```

and the markup is

```html
<li>
 <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMID_0">
  <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red"><input name="MM_0" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="MM_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
  Admin
 </span>
 <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="MMID_0" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
  <li>
   <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0">
    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_0_0" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
    Debtors-Creditors
   </span>
   <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="submenu_0_0" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0SM_0_00">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_00" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_00" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
      Read
     </span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0SM_0_10">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
      Create
     </span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0SM_0_20">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_20" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_20" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
      Update
     </span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0SM_0_30">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_30" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_30" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
      Delete
     </span>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__1">
    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_0_1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
    Users
   </span>
   <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="Smenu_0_1__1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 60px;">
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red">
      <input name="SM_0_1_1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_1_1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="2"></span>
      new subby tst3
     </span>
     <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="Smenu_0_1__10" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10SM_0_1_1_00">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled green checked">
        <input name="Pr_SM_0_1_1_00" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_1_1_00" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
        Read
       </span>
      </li>
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10SM_0_1_1_10">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red">
        <input name="Pr_SM_0_1_1_10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_1_1_10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
        Create
       </span>
      </li>
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10SM_0_1_1_20">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red">
        <input name="Pr_SM_0_1_1_20" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_1_1_20" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
        Update
       </span>
      </li>
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10SM_0_1_1_30">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_1_1_30" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_1_1_30" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
        Delete
       </span>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__2">
    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_0_2" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_2" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
    Contacts
   </span>
   <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="Smenu_0_1__2" style="padding-left: 60px;">
    <li></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" style="border: 2px solid red; border-image: none; color: red;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_3">
    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red">
    <input name="SM_0_3" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_3" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
    Security
   </span>
   <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="Smenu_0_1__2" style="padding-left: 60px;">
    <li></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

An image of the applied red border css.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know at which point you're trying to color the nodes (are they all loaded?), but I would try to grab the list by its head and use `.find()`

Maybe this will work in your case:

```
listHead.find('.accordion-heading').each(function () {
  $(this).css({ "color": "red", "border": "2px solid red" });
}
```

Comment: The point where I try get all parents is when there is a click event on a checkbox. In this case the Green ticked "Read" checkbox. From there I try find all parents with the class "accordion-heading", but the query misses a few of the parents and they definitely do have class="accordion-heading". Reason being , that I need to go up the parent tree (setting arrays) in order to accumulate the states of the various checkboxes and thus set each successive parent as a tristate checkbox depending on the children's "All Green, Some green or All red" (being permissions for a menu structure).

Comment: The css red border applied was just a check to see if my code was finding all the parents,..which it is strangely not getting right.

Comment: I think your suggestion of starting at the top and working down may be my only option. Save that into an object or array and then using some coded function, get my parent-sibling structure, per branch of the tree and accumulate Red +Green values, and set each's parent as one of 3 states. Wish that were not the case though.